which inputs can i use to exploit the buffer overflow in this program to execute the win() function
i want to use the overflow in some methods of the program to run another function win()

#define MAX_PRIORITY_STRSIZE 10 /* len(str(2**32)) */
#define MAX_TITLE_SIZE 0x20
#define MAX_TODOS 0x30

void win(void)
{
    execl("/bin/get_flag", "get_flag", NULL);
}

bool read_title(char* buf, size_t buf_size)
{
    if(!fgets(buf, buf_size, stdin))
    {
        printf("Could not read title...\n");
        return false;
    }

    if(buf[0] == '\n')
    {
        printf("Title cannot be empty!\n");
        return false;
    }

    /* Remove newline in title */
    strtok(buf, "\n");

    if(strlen(buf) > MAX_TITLE_SIZE)
    {
        printf("Title too long!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}



bool read_priority(char* priority_buf, size_t buf_size, int32_t* ret)
{
    printf("Priority: ");
    if(!fgets(priority_buf, buf_size, stdin))
    {
        printf("Could not read priority...\n");
        return false;
    }

    if(sscanf(priority_buf, "%d", ret) != 1)
    {
        printf("Invalid input!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void print_welcome(void)
{
    printf("Welcome to ToDo-List-as-a-Service Demo!\n"
             "Manage ToDo-List to your liking with a simple terminal interface!\n");
}


void print_menu(void)
{
    puts("=================================");
    puts(" What would you like to do next?");
    puts(" A: Add ToDo");
    puts(" C: Mark ToDo as completed");
    puts(" D: Delete ToDo");
    puts(" E: Edit ToDo Title");
    puts(" I: Increase Priority");
    puts(" L: List ToDos");
    puts(" P: Edit ToDo Priority");
    puts(" Q: Quit");
    puts("=================================");
    printf("> ");
}

The functions above are what's important for this question. During testing I've found that :

During add ToDo, if we input large amounts of numbers in priority, the title will be automatically part of the inputted numbers in priority without further entering the title, e.g.

a
Priority: 1111111111111111111111111111111
Title: ToDo '11111111111111111111' added!

If we edit said ToDo's priority to large amount of numbers, specifically more than 9 digits, the title also changes however into other numbers.

I'm sure this could be a buffer overflow problem and we could exploit this to run the win() program, but I don't know which inputs to put. I ran lldc (since I use a mac) and found out that win_address = 0x100003040
main_address = 0x1000039b0

read_title() and others are never called.  There is no complete code/program here.
